# Magento checkout jquery function null error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.8

I'm getting error TypeError: $(...) is null and TypeError: $(...).visible is null.

In onepage checkout jquery function which is  if($('checkout-step-shipping').visible() || $('checkout-step-shipping_method').visible())

Please let me know what may cause this problem

```
function styleRegionInterval() {
    if (!intervalInit) {
        styleRegion = setInterval(styleRegionInput, 500);
        intervalInit = true;
    }
}
function styleRegionInput() {
    if($('checkout-step-shipping').visible() || $('checkout-step-shipping_method').visible()) {
        clearInterval(styleRegion);
        intervalInit = false;
        shippingRegionUpdater.update();
    }
}
```

Some days before i had removed shipping method but my checkout was working fine without it.

There is same on billing or register page of checkout to continue button as function calls there.

Comment: Is this jQuery or Prototype? (looks like Prototype).

Comment: Magento1 or Magento2?

Comment: As i skipped shipping method in checkout. i have to remove checkout-shipping-method.visible() in condition as its not part of onepage. This solved my prblm. my magento version 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery('checkout-step-shipping').visible() instead of $('checkout-step-shipping').visible().

Your could should look like:

```
function styleRegionInterval() {
    if (!intervalInit) {
        styleRegion = setInterval(styleRegionInput, 500);
        intervalInit = true;
    }
}
function styleRegionInput() {
    if(jQuery('checkout-step-shipping').visible() || jQuery('checkout-step-shipping_method').visible()) {
        clearInterval(styleRegion);
        intervalInit = false;
        shippingRegionUpdater.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, jQuery selectors seems to be wrong: checkout-step-shipping   should be    .checkout-step-shipping    and     .visible()   shoud be    .is(':visible')

Comment: tnx for the response. My problem resolved as o had skipped checkout i just removed step-shipping-method.visible() frm condition it removed.